# Write MJPEG stream to disk

Tags: c#, mjpeg

How can I write an MJPEG stream to disk in C#? (AVI, MPEG or OGG)

Comment: Are you asking how to put an MJPEG stream into a container format (like AVI) using C#? Is your MJPEG stream already in memory? or are you trying to figure out how to read that into memory as well, too?

Answer (score 1):

You create a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) that will be the file you want to write to and use the MJPEG stream as an input to write to this stream.

Answer (score 1):

A library for reading/decoding MJPEG streams was recently released in C#, maybe it will help.  You can find it here:
http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/MJPEG-Decoder