# Save bitmaps to a mjpeg file using C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, bitmapimage, bitmapdata, mjpeg

I am trying to save bitmaps to an mjpeg file using C#.
I can save 1 image as a jpeg with

```
bitmap.Save("filename", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.jpeg);
```

In the above code, **bitmap is an object of type System.Drawing.Bitmap**.

I am parsing the images from another file (of custom format) or camera and want to pass them in mjpeg form to WCF. As a first step, I am trying to save mjpeg file.

How to save multiple images in the same file? The file would be using .mjpeg extension instead of .jpeg.

Edit:

Checked [Write MJPEG stream to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658742/write-mjpeg-stream-to-disk) but he is trying to save as a memory stream. I want to save it to a mjpeg file.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question.  You want multiple images in the same image file?

Comment: yes. Instead of jpeg, it would be saved as mjpeg

Comment: This also seems similar to what you are doing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595945/creating-my-own-mjpeg-stream

Answer (score 0):

You can open a file as a stream using [File.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.open(v=vs.110).aspx) and then use the approach you're pointing to in order to write the jpg's to that stream. Here's some pseudo code to illustrate:

```
using (var fileStream = File.Open("movie.mjpg"))
{
    foreach (var bitmap in listOfBitmaps) 
    {
        bitmap.Save(fileStream, Jeg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that instead of saving the bitmap as jpeg, I should be creating a file stream? I am parsing the images from another file or camera and want to pass them in mjpeg form to WCF. As a first step, I am trying to save mjpeg file.

Comment: @user2330678 - Hm, there clearly is some confusion here. Are you not able to write the jpg as a stream? ...it would perhaps help if you expand your question with what kind of object your `bitmap` variable is...

Comment: bitmap variable is of type System.Drawing.Bitmap. Edited the question.

Comment: @user2330678 - right, so if you open a file stream, then you can use bitmap.Save to write to the stream instead of directly to a file